# Unable to reload tabledata from UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to show different data in tableview on basis of selection from segmented control. Below is my code it only shows first TABLEVIEW DATASOURCE and for some reason segemented control doesn't work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var segementedControlAction: UISegmentedControl!


var Names = ["Name1", "Name2","Name3","Name4"]
var Images =  ["1.jpg","2.jpg","5.jpg","8.jpg"]
var set =  ["14","15","16","17"]

var Names1 = ["Name5", "Name6","Name7","Name8"]
var Images1 =  ["6.jpg","4.jpg","7.jpg","9.jpg"]
var set1 =  ["4","5","6","7"]

var Names2 = ["Name9", "Name12","Name13","Name14"]
var Images2 =  ["11.jpg","21.jpg","51.jpg","81.jpg"]
var set2 =  ["114","115","116","117"]


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count: Int = 0
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    if (tableView == self.d1) {
        print("Monday")
        count = self.Names.count
    }
    else if (tableView == self.d2) {
        print("Tuesday")
        count = self.Names1.count
    }
    else if (tableView == self.d3) {
        print("Wednesday")
        count = self.Names2.count
    }

    return count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
        indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

if segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    cell.nameLabel.text = Names[indexPath.row]
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: Images[indexPath.row])
    cell.setLabel.text = set[indexPath.row]

    }

else if segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

cell.nameLabel.text = Names1[indexPath.row]
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: Images1[indexPath.row])
cell.setLabel.text = set1[indexPath.row]
    }


else {segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 2

cell.nameLabel.text = Names2[indexPath.row]
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: Images2[indexPath.row])
cell.setLabel.text = set2[indexPath.row]

    }

    return cell }

@IBAction func segementedControlAction(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
 switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {

case 0:
self.d1.hidden = false
self.d2.hidden = true
self.d3.hidden = true

self.d1.reloadData()

case 1:

    self.d1.hidden = true
    self.d2.hidden = false
    self.d3.hidden = true
    self.d2.reloadData()

case 2:

    self.d1.hidden = true
    self.d2.hidden = true
    self.d3.hidden = false
    self.d3.reloadData()



default:
    self.d1.hidden = false
    self.d2.hidden = true
    self.d3.hidden = true

    self.d1.reloadData()
    break;

}
```

Comment: Are you saying `segementedControlAction:` is not getting triggered? Or its being triggered but table view is not reloaded with right data? I believe `d1`, `d2` & `d3` here are table views - why do you have 3 tables? You could have only one table and reload it with segment control based data.

Comment: Why do you have 3 table views? You just need 1.

Comment: yes segementedControlAction is not getting triggered and i need different tables to load from different selections in segemented Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that `segementedControlAction` is connected properly from your view controller. Probably try with these steps:

1. Delete the earlier connected `IBAction`.
2. Connect your segmentedControl to Files Owner.
3. Connect your `segementedControlAction:` action and select "Value
   Changed" NOT "Touch up Inside". THIS IS IMP.
4. Print a statement to check if `segementedControlAction:` is now
   triggered.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

In your viewDidLoad method, add this:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```